# I would like to know how array[array[i]]++ works in java

Tags: java

I would like to know how array[array[i]]++ works in java.
I wrote the code, and want to know how this count integer array is working here

```
int[] counts = new int[201];
        for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
            counts[array_inside[i]]++;
}
```

and 
also would like to know if i does like below how count array values will be written and left or right shift its values

```
for(int i = j; i < array_inside.length; i++){
count[array_inside[i-j]]--;
            count[array_inside[i]]++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider it as two operations (because it is). This

```
counts[array_inside[i]]++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int p = array_inside[i];
counts[p]++;
```

Comment: Elliott Frisch and how does increment operator is helping here, in counts[p]++;

Comment: The same way it works everywhere else, `counts[p] = counts[p] + 1;`